# BasicDataSource Support domain name？

Tags: java, url, datasource, dbcp

Now when customers use BasicDataSource, they want to change the URL connection string to a domain name. Is there a way to support this?

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
        </property><property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:orcl</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Is it feasible to change ip:port to domainName？

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@example.com:1521:orcl
```